# Comparison of the norms of two non-negative real-valued vectors differing only in one component.

Tags: normed-spaces

Let $0 \leq a \leq b$ and let $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R^{n}}$.  Let $\|.\|$ be a norm over $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.  If we write $(
\mathbf{x},a)$ the vector of $
\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ made by concatening $\mathbf{x}$ and $a$, does the follonig inequality holds?

\begin{equation}
\|(\mathbf{x},a)\| \leq \|(\mathbf{x},b)\|
\end{equation}

Intuitively, since all the components are positive, the going from $(\mathbf{x},a)$ to $(\mathbf{x},b)$ is a motion away from the origin, so the norm should at best keep the same, or we might have an issue with the triangle inequality somehow.  But I cannot figure how it could fail.

Thanks for any help !

Comment: is your norm a $\ell_p$ norm? then yes. otherwise I am not so sure.

Comment: No. But for some positive constant $M$, $||(x,a)||\leq M ||(x,b)||$. For an easy example, set $x=0$ and find a basis $\beta$ for $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Then the sum of absolute values of coordinates along $\beta$ is a norm on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. You can find a suitable basis.

Comment: I can't see why I need the constant $M$.  For example if $n = 0$, the theorem is true, as every norm on $\mathbb{R}$ has the form $\|x\| = M \cdot |x|$.  So if $0 \leq a \leq b$, we have $M \cdot |a| \leq M \cdot |b|$.  What can go wrong in higher dimension ?  I don't understand what the manhattan norm example showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, consider the norm
$$
\|(x,y)\| = x ^2- xy + y^2
$$
We note that
$$
\|(2,0)\| > \|(2,1)\|
$$
A class of norms that act the way you might expect is the set of "symmetric gauge functions", as referenced [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87768/a-question-on-gauge-functions).