# Norm of a vector component (considering an orthogonal basis) is always lesser than or equal to the norm of the entire vector in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Suppose $\mathbb R^n$ (with the usual dot product as inner product) is equipped with some arbitrary norm $||\cdot||$. Now let's say $\mathbf x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ is a vector in $\mathbb R^n$ (where $\{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\}$ are the components of $\mathbf x$ in any orthogonal basis of $\mathbb R^n$).

Can we always say that $||(0, \ldots, x_i, \ldots, 0)|| \leq ||\mathbf x||$ (where $1 \leq i \leq n$)? That is, is the norm of any component of a vector $\mathbf x$ in $\mathbb R^n$ always lesser than or equal to the norm of the entire vector $\mathbf x$? How does this follow from the definition of "norm"?

Comment: This is the triangle inequality, basically.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I was thinking of the triangle inequality, yes. But could you elaborate a bit on how to frame it?

Comment: @S.D. The answer is no. As an example where this does not hold, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4119130/define-a-norm-on-mathbbr3/4119143#4119143).

Comment: What does “orthogonal basis” mean in a context without an inner product?

Comment: @S.D. For a slightly simpler example, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1351392/81360)

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Ah, good point. I was thinking of the usual dot product as inner product in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: And therefore no connection is assumed between the norm $\|\cdot\|$ and the inner product?

Comment: @BenGrossmann I'm going through the counter-examples, but does this have anything to do with the positive-definiteness of the inner product inducing the norm as Matthew mentioned in his answer?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I'm not exactly sure about how assuming a connection (or not assuming a connection) between the norm and the inner product is relevant. I'm probably missing something important.

Comment: @S.D. Any inner product induces a norm; for an inner product $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$, we define $\|x\| = \sqrt{\langle x,x \rangle}$. Usually, if a vector space has both an inner product and a norm, then that is because the norm is induced by an inner product. What you seem to be interested in is a space that has an inner product and a norm that is not related to that inner product, which is strange.

Answer (score 3):

So I'm assuming this not some arbitrary norm, but a norm that arises from some arbitrary positive-definite inner product, and your use of *orthogonal* refers to that inner product.

You don't really need an entire basis, just a single unit vector.  The projection of any vector onto any unit vector will be shorter (or at most, exactly as long as) the given vector.

Given a vector $\mathbf{x}$, and a unit vector $\mathbf{u}$, there exists a real number $t$ and a vector $\mathbf{p}$ such that
$$
    \mathbf{x}= t\mathbf{u} + \mathbf{p}
$$
and $\mathbf{p}$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf{u}$.  In your notation, $\mathbf{u}$ is the $i$th basis vector, and $t$ is your $x_i$.

By the Pythagorean Theorem,
$$
    \Vert \mathbf{x} \Vert^2 = \Vert t \mathbf{u} \Vert^2 + \Vert \mathbf{p} \Vert^2 = t^2 + \Vert \mathbf{p} \Vert^2 \geq t^2
$$
So $|t| \leq \Vert \mathbf{x} \Vert$.

A generalization of this is [Parseval's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity).

José and Ben are pointing out that if the norm and inner product being considered aren't related to each other, the statement is false.

Comment: By the way, why does the norm need to arise from a positive-definite inner product in this context? Why exactly goes wrong if it doesn't?

Comment: @S.D. I was wrong in my first comment about the triangle inequality; my proof above really needs the Pythagorean theorem.  For that, you need a right triangle; which means you need “angles” as well as “lengths”.  “Lengths” require a norm, but “angles” require an inner product related to that norm by the [polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity).